# Open External URL in a new browser window from MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-controller

How do i open an external URL (say google.com) in a new browser window / tab from MVC controller button click based on the condition's of success/failure.So far i tried this

```
    //Controller code
  public ActionResult Index( ) 

  {

 --Do some logic
 if(logicpasses)
 {
        return Redirect("http://google.com"); -- This doesn't work out as it's navigating to the URL in the same tab

    return JavaScript("Window.open('http://google.com')"); -- This is not    working as  well
 }
else
{
 return Redirect("http://google.com");
}
}
```

Comment: window.open is not working? JS is case sensitive.... try lowercase window

Comment: It doesn't work even if i change it to lowercase

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.asp.net/t/1896548.aspx?Open+external+link+in+new+browser+page explains that the browser opening a new window should happen in the view because it's a client thing. The solution for me was to add 'target = "_blank"' to the actionlink in the view that passes control to the controller to load the URL. In view: @Html.ActionLink("strLabel", "Action", "Controller", new { id = idValue }, new { target = "_blank" }). In controller: return Redirect(yourUrl); this leaves the original view intact in the other tab and the new url in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I think redirecting to a new tab should be done on the client side instead of server side because it's related to the browser's behavior. As a workaround, I have 1 option you can consider.

**Views\Shared\OpenInNewTab.cshtml**

```
@model string
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('@Model', '_blank');
</script>
```

**Controllers (E.g. Home)**

```
public IActionResult OpenInNewTab(string url)
{
   return PartialView("OpenInNewTab", url);
}

public IActionResult HandleLogicButtonOnClicked()
{
   if (logicpasses)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("OpenInNewTab", "Home", new { url = "http://google.com" });
   }
   else
   {
       return Redirect("http://google.com");
   }
}
```

**Views**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "HandleLogicButtonOnClicked")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return JavaScript("window.open('http://google.com')");
```

this should work.